# regular expression to extract string from java code

Tags: java, regex

The sample source code to match is

```
String string="welcome";
String k="a\"welcome";
```

I am using `"(\"[^(\")]*\")"` regex in  java.

But this extracts

```
0:"welcome"
0:"a\"
```

Expected output is

```
0:"welcome"
0:"a\"welcome"
```

What change should i make in regex to get the expected output ?

Java source :

```
private static String pattern1="(\"[^(\")]*\")";
public void getStrings(){
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
    Matcher m = r.matcher("String string=\"welcome\";\n" +
            "String k=\"a\\\"welcome\";");


    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("0:"+m.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tell us what pattern is not matched, or better what's the principle of matching or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just use lookahead and lookbehind in your regex,,

```
(?<==)(".*?")(?=;)
```

Get the value from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vN2vU4/2)

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(?<==)(\".*?\")(?=;)");
Matcher m = r.matcher("String string=\"welcome\";\n" +
            "String k=\"a\\\"welcome\";");
while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("0:"+m.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
0:"welcome"
0:"a\"welcome"
```

**OR**

Use the greediness of `*`,

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\".*\")");
```

**OR**

It skips the double quotes which are preceded by a backslash,

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\\".*?(?<=[^\\\\])\\\")");
```

Comment: you could try this also http://regex101.com/r/vN2vU4/4 . It just skips the double quotes which are proceeded by a backslash.

Comment: or this, `(\".*?[^\\]\")`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even bother with variable assignment. You know that everything within `""` is a string.

`"(.+)"\s*;` should do it just fine.